# ng-model select dropdown update - angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, javascript-objects

Basically i have a select dropdown

```
<select class="form-control" id="ursel"
        ng-change="changeVal()"
        ng-options="a for a in RatedVoltage" data-ng-model="TechCharacters.selectedUr">
        <option value="" selected="selected">{{globalLangResource.SelectAny}}</option>
</select>
```

So on change of this select,  have results reflecting to another select

```
viewModel.changeVal = function(){
    var val = viewModel.TechCharacters.selectedUr; 
    if (val != undefined && val === "7.2kV") {
        $rootScope.ud = viewModel.InsulationVoltage["7.2kV"];  // 20,30,40  
    }
}
```

The 2nd dropdown looks like this

```
<select class="form-control" id="udsel"
        ng-change="setUd();"
        ng-options="a for a in ud" data-ng-model="TechCharacters.InsulVolt">
       <option value="" ng-if="false"></option>
</select>
```

Now i have a submit button, on submit,i am getting the main object.

```
console.log(TechCharacters);
```

Here i am not getting `TechCharacters.InsulVolt` value. it is showing empty.

If i have made change is the 2nd dropdown, the `model` is updated. until then i am not getting the changed model from 1st dropdown

Basically i want all the `ng-model` values inside form even it is changed or not.

Comment: both are different controller or same?

Comment: i cant see anything that will update `TechCharacters.InsulVolt` on first dropdown change.

Comment: @Matarishvan can u create this in a plunker and show ?

Comment: Using `$rootScope` to share data, especially at this small of a scale, is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 1):

if you want the first object of second dropdown on change of first one. change code to .

```
viewModel.changeVal = function(){
    var val = viewModel.TechCharacters.selectedUr; 
    if (val != undefined && val === "7.2kV") {
        $rootScope.ud = viewModel.InsulationVoltage["7.2kV"];  // 20,30,40  
        viewModel.TechCharacters.InsulVolt=$rootScope.ud[0]
    }
}
```

hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do this. This will work.

```
<select data-ng-model="TechCharacters.selectedUr"
    <option ng-selected="{{obj == TechCharacters.selectedUr}}" value="{{obj}}" ng-repeat="(key,value) in RatedVoltage">
</select>
```

Basically you are doing `ng-selected` and comparing the `ng-model` value with that of the `ng repeat` value, and the selected value will be shown.